# Generic struct with a reference to the same type but with any concrete type

Tags: generics, reference, rust, any

My intention is to create a struct that holds a reference to another one of a similar type, but with different generics to be used as a chain of linked objects.

The problem is that writing this using the `_` placeholder is not allowed:

> ```
> the type placeholder `_` is not allowed within types on item
> signatures
> ```
>
> [E0121](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0121)

I cannot simply give my struct another type parameter since the referenced object may reference another object too, and so on. This would lead to a very large number of type parameters, which is not practical.

I would like to find a way to change this implementation to make it work:

```
// The type parameters are:
// O: this Router's data type
// B: The parent router's data type
pub struct DataRouter<'a, O, B = O>
where
    O: 'a,
    B: 'a,
{
    parent: Option<&'a DataRouter<'a, B, _>>, // Here the problem `_`
    range: Option<Range<usize>>,
    data: Option<O>,
}
```

I can't simply put a parameter here as I would've to add it to the struct, which then would cause the same infinite loop of adding a type parameter.

Is there a way to hold a reference to a `DataRouter` with `B` data type which itself holds a reference to a parent `DataRouter` with an unknown data type? The struct has to know only the direct parent data type, not the one of the second parent.

If this cannot be fixed, can you suggest a different implementation that could work?

Comment: What are you going to do with `parent` that requires you to know its parent's type?

Comment: My intent is to be able to get the parent to use the DataRouters as a chain. Basically I just want to be able to return the `parent` with a getter method, so that I can use it from where I'll build the chain. There every DataRouter will process the data and return it; Then the data will be passed to the last router's parent and will be processed again; and so on, until the chain ends (None instead of `Some(parent)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't (and indeed cannot) care about the type of the parent's parent, introduce abstraction through a trait:

```
trait Parent {}

struct Nil;
impl Parent for Nil {}

pub struct DataRouter<'a, T, P>
where
    P: 'a,
{
    parent: Option<&'a P>,
    data: Option<T>,
}

impl<'a, T, P> Parent for DataRouter<'a, T, P> {}

fn main() {
    let a = DataRouter {
        parent: None::<&'static Nil>,
        data: Some(true),
    };
    let b = DataRouter {
        parent: Some(&a),
        data: Some(42),
    };
    let c = DataRouter {
        parent: Some(&b),
        data: Some("moo"),
    };
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I don't know how you managed to answer correctly in like 30 seconds, but it works. Now I know how to deal better with Rust trait system. Good job

Comment: Just curious as to why  we need the `Parent` trait here at all ? It would have worked even without it. Is it just to make sure that no other `type` go into the `parent`  field of `DataRouter` - other than a `DataRouter` or a `Nil` ?